# Not able to pull registry.k8s.io in Microk8s start

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, microk8s

I'm trying to kickstart a MicroK8s cluster but the Calico pod stays on Pending status because of a 403 error against the pull of registry.k8s.io/pause:3.7

This is the error:
`Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.7": failed to pull image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.7": failed to pull and unpack image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.7": failed to resolve reference "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.7": pulling from host registry.k8s.io failed with status code [manifests 3.7]: 403 Forbidden`

We're talking about a new server which might be missing some configuration.
The insecure registry, according to Microk8s documentation, is enabled at localhost:3200.
I've enabled the dns on the Microk8s but nothing has change.

If I try to pull from docker I get a forbidden error.

Comment: Can you add the steps you tried yourself to resolve the issue? This helps others to point you in a direction you might have missed looking at.

Comment: I ran today in the same issue… I then replace the node but got the same public IP… with which the error stayed. I created a new node with a new public IP and then it worked. Seems to be some ip address blocking in place?